# Best metric for classification-regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, regression, classification

Sorry for the weird title, I don't know how to better express my problem. I'm working with an insurance dataset to predict future claim costs for a given policy.

For anyone who has worked with insurance claim data, you know that the claims are heavily 0-weighted. I've run into the issue before where regression on the entire dataset does not perform well, due to the skew of the data, and the continuous-discrete distribution mix.

I've tried some Tweedie distributions in R to help with this disconnect, but I ended up going a different route.

I first decided to classify the data into "Claim Amount = 0" and "Claim amount != 0", by using a support vector classifier `sklearn.svm.svc`(with 98% training and 95% test accuracy), where if a claim amount is predicted to be != 0, it will be fed into a regression model to predict the incurred claim amount. I decided to go with ridge regression `sklearn.linear_model.Ridge` for this part, and achieved a relatively good $R^2$ of 0.67 for the test set (real world data, so I'm not expecting anything extraordinary).

So my question is, what is the best way to evaluate this composite model, specifically in python? Do you think the MSE would be a good metric? The only other model I can compare it to is a basic linear regression (on the entire dataset, without the pre-classification).

Of course, feel free to suggest alternatives to this two-part classification-regression model.

EDIT: To clarify, I chose these specific models (over neural networks, for example) because of their ability to be translated into simple math for different applications.

Comment: Separating out one category of data and modeling it differently makes a lot of sense. This is essentially a kind of mixture model, with the mixture components being a spike at 0 for the "no claim" category and a regression for the "one or more claims" category. Looking at this as a mixture might suggest other approaches, such as an expectation-maximization scheme for distinguishing the categories. About evaluation, my advice is let your assessment be the log likelihood. This is applicable to most kinds of models, including mixture models, and many others.

Comment: Log likelihood applies to any probabilistic model, which includes most of the models in common use. The only non-probabilistic model which comes to mind is the support vector machine. PS. This is a great question, but more suited to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I considered posting it on the stats forum, but decided against it when I realized I was going to mention the use of scikit learn. Thanks for your advice though, I'll be looking into log likelihood!

Comment: Glad to help. Despite the question about scikit-learn, this is mostly a conceptual question and only incidentally about programming, so I think you should reconsider stats.stackexchange.com.